# Dynatree toDict()

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

In the 
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/index.html

it says

```
toDict()
    Convert the tree into a JavaScript object.
    See node.toDict() for details.
```

Is there a way to initialize the tree from that object later? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting dict can be passed to `node.addChild()`.

Have a look at the copy/paste example, which basically does this:

```
var cb = sourceNode.toDict(..);
targetNode.addChild(cb);
```